# Umbraco 7 - Umbraco Forms checkbox stays always false

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-forms

In Umbraco **7.5.9** (and 7.5.9) i've encounter the following issue:

When saving my form, checkboxes are always posted as False
When viewing the record inside Umbraco, the values are False
When retrieving the field value, the value is False.
The recorddata in table UFRecords also shows json with false values for checkboxes
Example data in the database:

```
{'183fba08-5ed2-4a1a-8cc1-3364b0529e7e':'item 1, item 2','aec143aa-806c-43dd-9289-f9bcfb76065d':'False','eb357878-54cb-4a44-ba42-74959fd5b1cd':'False','a3491195-de34-47a9-dc1e-8bc5911dc604':'10-7-2018 00:00:00','7a19dfa1-98cb-4a08-b719-7fb5e96ea681':'Input 123','629e6d2f-10fd-4564-c6fc-30efc68ceb7a':'','f450c3ab-7fdd-4cc7-c246-d1171f4b983b':'No'}
```

Love to hear a working solution!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you have a Forms license you have official support via your umbraco.com profile I believe.

Comment: I also think it's a bug ;) I also reported it to Umbraco trough the Umbraco Forms helpdesk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried upgrading to Umbraco Forms 4.4.7. After the second attempt I managed to get it working. Also running the package created by Tim helpt:

https://our.umbraco.com/forum/umbraco-pro/contour/60744-Entries-have-dissappeared#comment-206075

After restoring my bootstrap markup, new and old Umbraco Form were working again.